# Restler not accepting boolean false

Tags: restler

In my Restler API class I have an object defined like so (with lots of other params)

```php
class PatchTaskObj extends TaskObj {
    /**
     * @var bool|null Whether or not this Task should be pinned to the top of the list {@required false}
     */
    public $pinned = null;
}
```

And then I attempt to use it in my PATCH method:

```php
  /**
   * Updates an existing Task record.
   *
   * @param int          $id   The SQL ident of the task you wish to update. {@min 1} {@from path}
   * @param PatchTaskObj $info The properties of the Task to update.
   *
   * @throws RestException 412 Thrown if at least one update isn't passed in.
   *
   * @status 204
   */
  function patch($id, PatchTaskObj $info)
```

If I pass in `true` for the `pinned` property it works fine, but if I pass `false` then I get a 400 from Restler with the message:

> Bad Request: Invalid value specified for `info[pinned]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, discovered that Restler's Validator.php is failing to parse the @var property the way it's written.  If you remove the `|null` part then it works as expected.  I've submitted an issue to the github site.